# Codeigniter routing how to permit null parameter

Tags: codeigniter-routing

I want paginate my index http:localhost/mysite/home but if I write only this http:localhost/mysite/home the page said: "page not found", but if I write http:localhost/mysite/home/3 its work! how to I can configure my routing to get null parameters? I tried with (:any) and (num) but not work

My  route file is:

```
       $route['404_override'] = 'welcome/no_found';
       $route['home/'] = "welcome/home/$1";
```

My controller:

```
      $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'/mysite/home';
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->mtestmodel->countNews();
      $config['per_page'] = 2; 
      $config['num_links']   = 20;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
      $data['paginator']=$this->pagination->create_links();
      $data['news']=$this->mtestmodel->show_news( $config['per_page'],intval($to) );
```

//$to is a parameter in url  base_url()/mysite/home/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `route.php` file to the following:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'welcome/no_found';
$route['home/(:num)']  = "welcome/home/$1";
$route['home']         = "welcome/home";
```

This way, your application will catch both requests (`http://localhost/mysite/home` and `http://localhost/mysite/home/3`), and will send them both to your controller.

You should then be able to access your `$to` variable (which has been passed as the first argument into your controller's function) or use `$this->uri->segment(2)` instead.

e.g.

```
public function home($to = 0) {
    $config['base_url']    =  base_url().'/mysite/home';
    $config['total_rows']  = $this->mtestmodel->countNews();
    $config['per_page']    = 2; 
    $config['num_links']   = 20;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data['paginator']     = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['news']          = $this->mtestmodel->show_news( $config['per_page'],intval($to) );

}
```

Hope that helps!